# Как избавиться от рывка animation при повторном заходе на вкладку

Tags: css, анимация, css-animation

У меня есть такая анимация облаков:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000) no-repeat center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.banner .clouds {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner .clouds img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: animate calc(8s * var(--i)) linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

section {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

section h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="clouds">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HYOFIdSEozedbPcCO08K_ksED3OL4r8VeVbSvlWNerPtzykQxc-l1f_0Q7LvEm874Xszt04wqKdMpedVv0zIanR7BkWuYijyphP0rU5npsPY8qjcJaDUjwWo74GEfk5sWZrmGTBc8uB94HaRV6rbbiKjZxef5_nQu-4BykY_MU4_Tcejwb77aY36AN1IUu9K2ZF2rvedSh0VglhZTytvXCt4NU5AE4AUYu6As3DYkJG-f7hMNOWF03irvYTLMy_MmXFn-6WjVyedVQ6NMO7wY85_nMbu2OVdzQ-7DBXP9IQiue2RRQQ6hQSTQXGudgYPKp_AiaK__JWDsfjgls40qZGkEOx1pri36HuWdDSAEZ9Ph8qWl9VuFugquHanSctyjFOp5-3xNagxvzpVmfu_vt8tmCzasKfr9F0MUQTfmy6WimG6ViSt_KO_fOTb25CruzFZujvCL3At7JsAz4MAfz8dazhCeVVJJp3hwz5wuJS5Yd1Qn9CX_KOlmlXc2pS7zS88_S2Zs8znFfSCfUryZr92JZyUGYuJ6Vni8chKGEO4g13OOG-dn9t5Qetk-S_SiCqCrrBbWrJLHDICMb7wC1pc_rd3LBUk2n08Y5P1CJa-hhzbUHM-j0650CyCXcezF0HgRK86agV1WMTklCl1UwAwlatYWrNcyl_07IQ0hMnjn1K9_BQeoLVnSC5XQIanIbnA=w1919-h947-ft"
      style="--i:1">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5mvan3wmp-w1vWlq8c9Jv_dlU7HTNpdrayWJm5Cjm6Z9i2znsG9nE1GCZ4gk5m6cxZcEq3IQ5z5mhiAc_MEWLQpoJMZcE9VNqZJCxUD-85NAKHbHFFLGZHbiCJPAcTMT7qiBOXP490NQ2nVXG6wYVnN6Ry5sY4jhSpAD05UDKuqeH1a1otp2kEGWV8_DhW80Qk3GxPQ65tXsHSl975O8CacDqv4lOCC0ZMvVavluryPOIIjOzB_zCa3GEwyVnOvFdre7IRkWur-Cytxtpbrhqaybs_GL2_H5X-7wj0b3ryNsCFQyrRrvrIQZP0DIS8QDyj_HmDlzUBPa4WKPH6bn3RdDawE7OLCncHMd8bGHHnzb6anhU5iXnmsQPliNlzPhnpsbNUzCcFRH6wZ4u-ilYJcIL1J8vNPeAlhq-SjNiYKEe-n1BmijrdC-arH8vwGhQYz_GrIOznmDoxq8q0oRhDpktyw7GtGNIqdE9OoFz_emC97xz8EQ7XsfdKve_BVMy8lxXnEe8Kdbw6E0_a9bIHIajzuElyNqejXCW6yZnz45VHfzKyLGraN06JCQGYbSKMUCbk3maoVxccjb38NjfZVb4m3Zu571dW8-4KeIWdVoWRFe4Iw8l_sb5YD4MbZ_M3X277Ctp1CL21H4HlsJTtWbqnuBYUUoyTJpcm8vigM4uWYN5e71yl6aDCdjbGu6l-_D=w1919-h947-ft"
      style="--i:2">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/3I_RWn8GmvbZk-rRJx0-AQNld6WowOKrLP-FPffpWTo--TQwBgT3aUikrsupsFEtl86cuohBlhUXY7PIPkXZTVqXxy7HdSc-cugH9fGJinNQchJFaWhKDPXBK-XZhFOGGemcBh8zddI4e1OVXAv2YwXTYxMCXsOO8AxGvYJHYL8r4eHokxV0ZC_et5cU21c3HlWjZK-R6QCNFU21hkacNRczBbQ2JCPrfoRbo3dFm1y2Ibczl326ExcTzrUVY7y4AtBjFuNJW195rbajdwGSBBKxfcymVHmQ9j5owovdX5lrGjIm2BYTfs4uMDwPKOh6hIVaAo8jCqkAjGd9shiJxnDUuClYYq6JcwKGBTyDsftMTaDWtKJbGy3ayT6cZ_OmlvafkrsNfAaPu1yTFVWWMcaRij8yZTO74S5qQzNiQAiugD8_Mfn5lobl1kI8Q6ZfV6nMVLFGYPXiR2dw-l-BcyYu6-G-PCuk1TXx1w9BLZnuMLnh30pzJGbxL_YI2zk1B__mwbt_Olzl98gmQRGB6H5FH0vuRqkqv9zjszJI-44aJUHELFawUBAZNxdYEGss26iTGeDL_zHtn2-QBgfa1WGrAXqVZio8IaE6LvXz1jnoPmT_CLEs1ZHJXxlIxnbYiSt53oa-7GI9hoqULUqfQzVtjE0wjpbU-GaJjGO-TNQq4ffUh5rHRzYZFQVX9m7nhqGn=w830-h947-ft"
      style="--i:3">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uLultoDSQUnW41gQzV3Y1ZUv-iHApQ_jVcvn6_sAOAWTYdHxk1VBGRIC-PVZXk7woUc0Q0AErWMNqTf5IGc0VLY_U2lrvFTKE8ic2mLafQOCLRSv9qiwic5NE1qrqYMpO5_Kbx9gfVS6PduQtx1SX_nm7BjyLJpW_0cXRaMR9r-4XilrILw3wQD7jmSAQGJzdNS_VWyIFHIa7GaGyDHLFMD06q_WCVWhd7i0H3EvT35-HMa9eGP_jYJPOBlGJSSvw_ht1jTCXo8AXY-yYeRnbj5smEQGj6AHvscrETYTLh9PJhy7iJ9YQKknvxGPn4Za3ZFM0do_FvQ-bogDMn3G6WrkZ8Q9UAyOfU_OlLOkDs4h0tkklpuZOMLhiHWnq9lh9P7APgpxFiqodDY5MOEtl8Lweli3ca2IvyweQgEuQ4VNL3A1csVwiMd8ufGWPzsdJFUuVSzY-NE9VojmNO5CpvQ91K2sLQZVQCIRJIcRwgTsIgd6zS7Xwlgtwmdbx-4RsWbU_nRl5YebyDf1hENT9-epY8Jyy-Vk87QeydXIL2oqrRhtyaMAgciSBSlyow12ElD_pl58Kz7_9OfluLzqy7wcL0EkM62GltYubrhyFKKlIefcIqjbIaNYyKlVHoqmKyz1cy4Xy4e5PwNYlhiifYwifWCz51ydeRaUwnxtyZCMq4kVzi_wqGb2qa1GuXJDFNbu=w830-h947-ft"
      style="--i:4">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ovV6xb41xzr9EOIQPqKbh-F33WmvxLOM9Af1gmJBYUmwLaB-fjc_O_6Ld19lOM4MfVf4Xcmouj1uPXJB4nFmRk3bv49cjB93qOZYKtXKQYySsaYwwYtivM3EA3UHCIIYEkca6TKGUHdC4_piEIsRTk40XPrRlhjQlodvvNXRI8A5h4agIbKyURemWfReUMColrBYlxHHAlTuUlx8uDe1_l2OhXq2mFfeb-FZ_iJGNyjZ3Rh4GpqCY0yPqItye92kwuWzM2e4K3OPQFukkyFmaH30nYYYFMc24pCOStFcL7Xzz1KbfitFs9DEh0l74wkrJW4qpic-P4vVgYpKh11f7wpmRj5W2KQRnibnq4jz3Rh-NxKTuF8RZW7x_0C9xp0tg0NWV7wZKJtiQ28mtwd_4X1oRRznk4Ron_8mpyCRf98nf5B8PpLh8XJNyCE4lUOihEKYRvO-6zrxOQ244GbHLS0SPNbNk5by6ji5TjB-yt21z7iag4XbtQZSpYXMqeI2bGl-znOGZAeAwAKiO_0BAPh3YQQC5NKHAGRcmsvUI0aXZRcR0hrfc8YfZ6JJ_tFDLHEdDFCS_H-em3LTbnXjjNaaLeHUmWg2geqACPjllaytmKL2g8UNTXtwhlPUXumBF1ZicDDsiP6pavWxiWmFJHKgBlt3Xb1xihnbfynu5ndjyTx0xFSZnmskE3ZRdpwUBt0U=w830-h947-ft"
      style="--i:5">
  </div>
</div>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>CSS Cloud Banner Animation Effects</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio, quisquam asperiores inventore laudantium ea! Deserunt repudiandae quas ex. Velit accusantium ratione voluptas saepe repellat. Ducimus blanditiis dolorem, inventore similique aspernatur.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Но есть проблема, когда ты переходишь на другую ссылку в браузере, а потом во вкладку с облаками, они делают резкий рывок, что очень неприятно, как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 0):

Походу тебе надо стартовать анимации этих облаков, только после того как все img загрузились.(и не раньше) тогда скачков не должно быть.
Отслеживай через JS загрузку изображения, и если ок, то добавляй класс который будет запускать анимацию. По умолчанию картинки не анимируй

```
image.onload = function(){
//display ok addClass ....}
```

Comment: Тогда анимация начнётся заново, да?

Comment: не, идея в том, что б не запускать анимации, пока картинок нету в браузере клиента. У тебя браузер старается "догнать" тайминг анимации и показать пользователю что там происходило

Comment: Не работает так, сделал ответ и я не понимаю как написать условие, типа: если объект не загружен то делай это, иначе это

Answer (score 0):

[@BlackStar1991](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/228553/blackstar1991) всё также происходит

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.clouds img');
images.forEach((elem, i) => {
  elem.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const str = `animate ${8*(i+1)}s linear infinite`;
    elem.style.animation = str;
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000) no-repeat center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.banner .clouds {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner .clouds img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

section {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

section h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="clouds">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HYOFIdSEozedbPcCO08K_ksED3OL4r8VeVbSvlWNerPtzykQxc-l1f_0Q7LvEm874Xszt04wqKdMpedVv0zIanR7BkWuYijyphP0rU5npsPY8qjcJaDUjwWo74GEfk5sWZrmGTBc8uB94HaRV6rbbiKjZxef5_nQu-4BykY_MU4_Tcejwb77aY36AN1IUu9K2ZF2rvedSh0VglhZTytvXCt4NU5AE4AUYu6As3DYkJG-f7hMNOWF03irvYTLMy_MmXFn-6WjVyedVQ6NMO7wY85_nMbu2OVdzQ-7DBXP9IQiue2RRQQ6hQSTQXGudgYPKp_AiaK__JWDsfjgls40qZGkEOx1pri36HuWdDSAEZ9Ph8qWl9VuFugquHanSctyjFOp5-3xNagxvzpVmfu_vt8tmCzasKfr9F0MUQTfmy6WimG6ViSt_KO_fOTb25CruzFZujvCL3At7JsAz4MAfz8dazhCeVVJJp3hwz5wuJS5Yd1Qn9CX_KOlmlXc2pS7zS88_S2Zs8znFfSCfUryZr92JZyUGYuJ6Vni8chKGEO4g13OOG-dn9t5Qetk-S_SiCqCrrBbWrJLHDICMb7wC1pc_rd3LBUk2n08Y5P1CJa-hhzbUHM-j0650CyCXcezF0HgRK86agV1WMTklCl1UwAwlatYWrNcyl_07IQ0hMnjn1K9_BQeoLVnSC5XQIanIbnA=w1919-h947-ft">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5mvan3wmp-w1vWlq8c9Jv_dlU7HTNpdrayWJm5Cjm6Z9i2znsG9nE1GCZ4gk5m6cxZcEq3IQ5z5mhiAc_MEWLQpoJMZcE9VNqZJCxUD-85NAKHbHFFLGZHbiCJPAcTMT7qiBOXP490NQ2nVXG6wYVnN6Ry5sY4jhSpAD05UDKuqeH1a1otp2kEGWV8_DhW80Qk3GxPQ65tXsHSl975O8CacDqv4lOCC0ZMvVavluryPOIIjOzB_zCa3GEwyVnOvFdre7IRkWur-Cytxtpbrhqaybs_GL2_H5X-7wj0b3ryNsCFQyrRrvrIQZP0DIS8QDyj_HmDlzUBPa4WKPH6bn3RdDawE7OLCncHMd8bGHHnzb6anhU5iXnmsQPliNlzPhnpsbNUzCcFRH6wZ4u-ilYJcIL1J8vNPeAlhq-SjNiYKEe-n1BmijrdC-arH8vwGhQYz_GrIOznmDoxq8q0oRhDpktyw7GtGNIqdE9OoFz_emC97xz8EQ7XsfdKve_BVMy8lxXnEe8Kdbw6E0_a9bIHIajzuElyNqejXCW6yZnz45VHfzKyLGraN06JCQGYbSKMUCbk3maoVxccjb38NjfZVb4m3Zu571dW8-4KeIWdVoWRFe4Iw8l_sb5YD4MbZ_M3X277Ctp1CL21H4HlsJTtWbqnuBYUUoyTJpcm8vigM4uWYN5e71yl6aDCdjbGu6l-_D=w1919-h947-ft">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/3I_RWn8GmvbZk-rRJx0-AQNld6WowOKrLP-FPffpWTo--TQwBgT3aUikrsupsFEtl86cuohBlhUXY7PIPkXZTVqXxy7HdSc-cugH9fGJinNQchJFaWhKDPXBK-XZhFOGGemcBh8zddI4e1OVXAv2YwXTYxMCXsOO8AxGvYJHYL8r4eHokxV0ZC_et5cU21c3HlWjZK-R6QCNFU21hkacNRczBbQ2JCPrfoRbo3dFm1y2Ibczl326ExcTzrUVY7y4AtBjFuNJW195rbajdwGSBBKxfcymVHmQ9j5owovdX5lrGjIm2BYTfs4uMDwPKOh6hIVaAo8jCqkAjGd9shiJxnDUuClYYq6JcwKGBTyDsftMTaDWtKJbGy3ayT6cZ_OmlvafkrsNfAaPu1yTFVWWMcaRij8yZTO74S5qQzNiQAiugD8_Mfn5lobl1kI8Q6ZfV6nMVLFGYPXiR2dw-l-BcyYu6-G-PCuk1TXx1w9BLZnuMLnh30pzJGbxL_YI2zk1B__mwbt_Olzl98gmQRGB6H5FH0vuRqkqv9zjszJI-44aJUHELFawUBAZNxdYEGss26iTGeDL_zHtn2-QBgfa1WGrAXqVZio8IaE6LvXz1jnoPmT_CLEs1ZHJXxlIxnbYiSt53oa-7GI9hoqULUqfQzVtjE0wjpbU-GaJjGO-TNQq4ffUh5rHRzYZFQVX9m7nhqGn=w830-h947-ft">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uLultoDSQUnW41gQzV3Y1ZUv-iHApQ_jVcvn6_sAOAWTYdHxk1VBGRIC-PVZXk7woUc0Q0AErWMNqTf5IGc0VLY_U2lrvFTKE8ic2mLafQOCLRSv9qiwic5NE1qrqYMpO5_Kbx9gfVS6PduQtx1SX_nm7BjyLJpW_0cXRaMR9r-4XilrILw3wQD7jmSAQGJzdNS_VWyIFHIa7GaGyDHLFMD06q_WCVWhd7i0H3EvT35-HMa9eGP_jYJPOBlGJSSvw_ht1jTCXo8AXY-yYeRnbj5smEQGj6AHvscrETYTLh9PJhy7iJ9YQKknvxGPn4Za3ZFM0do_FvQ-bogDMn3G6WrkZ8Q9UAyOfU_OlLOkDs4h0tkklpuZOMLhiHWnq9lh9P7APgpxFiqodDY5MOEtl8Lweli3ca2IvyweQgEuQ4VNL3A1csVwiMd8ufGWPzsdJFUuVSzY-NE9VojmNO5CpvQ91K2sLQZVQCIRJIcRwgTsIgd6zS7Xwlgtwmdbx-4RsWbU_nRl5YebyDf1hENT9-epY8Jyy-Vk87QeydXIL2oqrRhtyaMAgciSBSlyow12ElD_pl58Kz7_9OfluLzqy7wcL0EkM62GltYubrhyFKKlIefcIqjbIaNYyKlVHoqmKyz1cy4Xy4e5PwNYlhiifYwifWCz51ydeRaUwnxtyZCMq4kVzi_wqGb2qa1GuXJDFNbu=w830-h947-ft">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ovV6xb41xzr9EOIQPqKbh-F33WmvxLOM9Af1gmJBYUmwLaB-fjc_O_6Ld19lOM4MfVf4Xcmouj1uPXJB4nFmRk3bv49cjB93qOZYKtXKQYySsaYwwYtivM3EA3UHCIIYEkca6TKGUHdC4_piEIsRTk40XPrRlhjQlodvvNXRI8A5h4agIbKyURemWfReUMColrBYlxHHAlTuUlx8uDe1_l2OhXq2mFfeb-FZ_iJGNyjZ3Rh4GpqCY0yPqItye92kwuWzM2e4K3OPQFukkyFmaH30nYYYFMc24pCOStFcL7Xzz1KbfitFs9DEh0l74wkrJW4qpic-P4vVgYpKh11f7wpmRj5W2KQRnibnq4jz3Rh-NxKTuF8RZW7x_0C9xp0tg0NWV7wZKJtiQ28mtwd_4X1oRRznk4Ron_8mpyCRf98nf5B8PpLh8XJNyCE4lUOihEKYRvO-6zrxOQ244GbHLS0SPNbNk5by6ji5TjB-yt21z7iag4XbtQZSpYXMqeI2bGl-znOGZAeAwAKiO_0BAPh3YQQC5NKHAGRcmsvUI0aXZRcR0hrfc8YfZ6JJ_tFDLHEdDFCS_H-em3LTbnXjjNaaLeHUmWg2geqACPjllaytmKL2g8UNTXtwhlPUXumBF1ZicDDsiP6pavWxiWmFJHKgBlt3Xb1xihnbfynu5ndjyTx0xFSZnmskE3ZRdpwUBt0U=w830-h947-ft">
  </div>
</div>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>CSS Cloud Banner Animation Effects</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio, quisquam asperiores inventore laudantium ea! Deserunt repudiandae quas ex. Velit accusantium ratione voluptas saepe repellat. Ducimus blanditiis dolorem, inventore similique aspernatur.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Можешь, ещё попробовать отслеживать событие когда пользователь покидаем страницу window.onblur = function () {document.title='документ неактивен'}
и подключить на это событие паузу для всей анимации, а когда вернется, опять play